# A bit confused about a part of the proof of Cauchy Hadamard theorem in Sarason

Tags: complex-analysis

I am currently reading Sarason and I am trying to show that $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n(z - z_0)$ radius of converge is equal to $\frac{1}{\lim \sup |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}}$.(we will assume $z_0 = 0$). Let $R$ be the radius of converge for the series i.e. $R:= \sup {|z - z_0|: \text{ where the series converges}}$.

The author first states that we are trying to show that $R \geq \frac{1}{\sup |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}}$.

Suppose $\rho > \frac{1}{\lim \sup |a_n|^\frac{1}{n}}$. Then from the limit superior, we know that there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\rho > |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$ for every $n \geq N$. Since $|\rho^n z^n| \geq |a_nz^n|$, then we know the radius of convergence of $\sum |\rho^n z^n|$ is equal to $\frac{1}{\rho}$ because it's a geometric series.

From an exercise in the textbook, Let $\sum a_nz^n$ and $\sum b_nz^n$ be power series with radii of $R_1$ and $R_2$. If there exists an $M > 0$ such that $|a_n| \leq M |b_n|$ for all but finitely many, then $R_2 \leq R_1$.

My proof, We know that $\exists M > 0:\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}:\forall n \geq n_0:|a_n| \leq M |b_n|$. Notice that $$|a_nz^n| = |a_n||z^n| \leq M|b_n||z^n| = M |b_nz^n|$$
Let $K_2$ denote the set where $\sum b_nz^n$ converges. Suppose $w \in K_2$. Hence, $\sum b_nw^n$ is Cauchy. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and set $\delta := \frac{\epsilon}{M}$. We know that there exists an $N \geq n_0$ such that $$\sum_{k = 0}^n |b_kz^k| - \sum_{k = 0}^m |b_kz^k| \leq \delta = \frac{\epsilon}{M}$$ for every $m > n \geq N$. Because $$\sum_{k = 0}^n |a_kz^k| - \sum_{k = 0}^m |a_kz^k| \leq M(\sum_{k = 0}^n |b_kz^k| - \sum_{k = 0}^m |b_kz^k|) < \epsilon$$for every $m > n \geq N$, then $\sum a_nw^n$ is Cauchy. Because $\mathbb{C}$ is complete, then $\sum a_nw^n$ converges. Thus, $R_1 \geq R_2$.

From this lemma, then $R \geq \frac{1}{\rho}$. The part I am confused about is when the author states "since $\rho$ can be taken arbitrary close to $\lim \sup |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$, we can obtain $R \geq \frac{1}{\lim \sup |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}}$", but $\rho > \lim \sup |a_n|^\frac{1}{n}$ from our assumption.

Comment: The proof is complicated in my opinion. It can be simplified if we observe that $R=\sup \{|z|\,:\, a_nz^n\to  0\}.$